# Use .babelrc outside of root

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I have the current folder structure:

```
src/
    package.json
    .babelrc
    themes/
        theme1/
            package.json
        theme2/
            package.json
```

When I run Babel on the `src` directory, it compiles all the files within perfectly, using the root `.babelrc`, however, when it comes to the theme directories, it did not compile the files correctly (ie. it did not use the root Babel config in terms of plugins/presets).

Each theme has it's own `node_modules` (for clarification), as they need their own modules.

Each theme would be compiled using the same root Babel configuration, so my workaround solution was to place a cloned `.babelrc` in each theme directory. This worked fine, but not ideal.

My question is, why when there's a package.json present in each theme directory, did Babel not attempt to use the root `babel.rc`

My Babel command was super simple: `babel src --out-dir dist`

Comment: Do your `package.json` files have a `babel` field in them?

Comment: @loganfsmyth nope, just deps: `{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "js/layout.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-linkify": "^0.2.2"
  }
}`

Comment: Which `babel` version are you using?

Comment: You best option atm is to use `--config-file ../.babelrc`, that is better than copy/paste it to every theme directory

Comment: @FernandoMontoya good shout. Because I also want to compile the parent directory too, not just the child theme directories. Guessing I can explicitly tell it where to look for the config file

Comment: If you're using babel 7, I suggest you take a look at https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#configuration-file-types